# sending sms programmatically in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Im trying to send an sms programmatically and in ios 6 its works perfect but in ios 7 its not working. Its open a white view with nothing inside and just stuck my app!

my code looks like this:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageVC = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
[messageVC setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

    NSString *smsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bla bla bla"];
    messageVC.body = smsString;
    messageVC.recipients = @[userPhone];
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:messageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

please help!! ios7 driving me crazy!

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Are you testing on the simulator or device?

Comment: both but in simulator its sais "text messaging is not availble" and in the devies its go to a white view with nothing on it

Comment: Firstly, don't create the `messageVC` object outside of the 'if' statement. You only need it if text sending is possible. Secondly, like I said, your code is working fine for me in a bare-bones project. Maybe we need to see some more code to work out what's going wrong.

Comment: witch code u need to see? and u using ios 7?

Comment: I got a warning like this: Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <UITabBarController: 0x16d4ca80> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Comment: I'm using the latest Xcode (from the App Store) and iOS 7. Where are you dismissing the view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine, but the message "Text messaging is not available" is given on devices that are not capable to send messages. I tested on an iPad Mini and it's working fine.